# mplab: cx8- компилятор не видит заголовочный файл <p18f4585.h>

Tags: c, pic

На `MPLAB X IDE v4.20` установил `xc8-v2.00-full-install-windows-installer.exe` Но почему то не могу работать с микропроцессором p18f4585.

Подключал `#include <p18cxxx.h>` но не видит файл .

тоже не видит файл :

```
#elif defined(__18F4585)
  #include <p18f4585.h>
```

*не совершает сборку проекта.*

Искал дополнительные библиотеки  и не нашёл их, так и не понял где достать эту библиотеку ??
Как работать с чипом p18f4585 ??

Comment: А что конкретно не заработало? Не компилирует? Не заливает прошивку? Программатор не видит камень? Какой программатор?

Comment: @user269134 ок, добавил

Comment: .h файл это не библиотека, а по сути такой мапер. У каждого контроллера разные адреса на разные регистры, потому в этих хэдерах хранятся define - ы на конкретный контроллер. Что выдаёт компилятор при попытке сборки? Если зажать CTRL и щёлкнуть мышкой по include, переход к файлу p18f4585.h происходит?

Comment: @user269134 не не переходит. ругается на   `#include <p18f4585.h> `

Comment: Попробуйте искать его иначе в пустых кавычках <> через CTRL + Пробел, структура папок с хэдерами там достаточно разветвлённая. Также если это какой-то специфичный камень, то скорее всего есть что-то более общее по типу p18а45xx.h.

Comment: @user269134 меня поражает другое, если собранный проект , я беру и подключ. в мплаб . И оппа . Оказывается у меня какой то не такой xc8 . Я тянусь за этой `p18f4585.h` - хренью в интернет, и ничё не получаю ;_;

Comment: @user269134 p18а45xx.h такой тоже нету ;_;

Comment: @user269134 оформи пожалуйста ответ  : ** Попробуйте искать его иначе в пустых кавычках <> через CTRL + Пробел, просто если вы переносите проект из mplab ide v8 project работая при этом в MPLAB X IDE v4.20 то даже используя, тот же компилятор название заголовочного файла может поменяться `#include <pic18f4585.h>` вот такой я нашёл и полностью всё собралось. ** Все таки вы дали прекрасный ответ и хотелось бы закрыть вопрос , если в течение двух дней не опубликуете то я сам выложу ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте искать его иначе, в пустых кавычках `<>` через <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>Пробел</kbd>.

---

*Комментарий автора вопроса : переносил проект из **mplab ide v8**  в **MPLAB X IDE v4.20**  тот же компилятор (xc8), название заголовочного файла было `#include <p18f4585.h>` при переносе надо было поменять на  `#include <pic18f4585.h>` . После прошедшего пути всё полностью собралось :3.*

Comment: [Правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/296638)  адресована автору сообщения и, по сути, правкой не является. Её стоит опубликовать в форме комментария или ответа.